# How do I concatenate columns of dummified dataset

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm struggling with concatenating some columns which I converted the corresponding data using the get_dummies function. I ran the code: `titanic_data = ps.concat([titanic_data,sex,Pcl])`, but the concatenated columns generated null values. How do I amend this?

Comment: Share the code and expected output?

Comment: If you are trying to concatenate the columns, you should pass the parameter `axis = 1`

Comment: welcome to SO community. please review the link here regarding how to ask a good question in SO ([howtoask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). you question lack of basic debugging data/code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate as columns, use `axis=1`

Eg:

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.concat([titanic, sex, Pcl], axis=1))
```